# multitenant not loading parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, multi-tenant

this is my code and it is not working:

```
        services.AddMultiTenant<SampleTenantInfo>()
            .WithConfigurationStore()
            .WithRouteStrategy()
            .WithPerTenantAuthentication()
            .WithPerTenantOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>((options, tenantInfo) => {
                //options.ResponseType = tenantInfo.ResponseType;
                options.Authority = tenantInfo.OpenIdConnectAuthority;
                options.ClientId = tenantInfo.OpenIdConnectClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = tenantInfo.OpenIdConnectClientSecret;
                options.ResponseType = "code";
            });
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
    {
        options.Prompt = "login consent"; // For sample purposes.
                });
```

what I'm trying to solve: this is meant to be an application that allows multiple logins but one per user, so I have several tenants, and the user is meant to select one of them and then the idea is that there is an openidconnect that is set per tenant, so the user gets redirected to login to the selected tenant.

What I have done:

in the beginning, my code didnot include the withpertenantoptions, and I could only login in one of the tenants, but not in the other one, debugging it I saw that ResponseType was not set, so I added withpertenantoptions, to set up just the response type but the rest of the parameters were not loaded, then I added the rest of the parameters depending on the tenant but they are still coming null. They are kept in a appsettings.file.

I am using Finbuckle to deal with the multitenant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was simple, I was setting up oidc options twice, so I was taking the bad ones, solution is to remove     {
options.Prompt = "login consent"; // For sample purposes.
}

and then set up everything in the other options